# Using parallax scrolling for a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, custom-scrolling

I am looking to create a simple parallax scrolling effect on an image view that is embedded in a UIScrollView in swift (actually, I have the image embedded in a view that is, in turn, embedded in the UIScrollview). This is the layout I am working with:

[image: PageLayout]

As you can see from the screenshot above, the image is larger than the UIImageView to which it is assigned. When the user scrolls down the screen I would like other (vertical) portions of the image to become visible, such as in the example given in [this tutorial](http://www.michaelbabiy.com/parallax-scroll-view-in-swift/). The tutorial, however, uses a collection view to display a mutable array of images and I could not figure out how to adapt it to my purposes. Does anyone have an idea as to how to accomplish this?